# Trying to build solution of visual studio 2010 in TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I am trying to build solution of project built in Visual Studio 2010 in TFS 2012.

It gives me the following error:

> Unable to resolve `'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinForm.UltraFormManager, Infragistics2.Win.v12.1, Version=12.1.20121.2008, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'

Is this because the project was built in VS2010 and I am trying to run it in VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using TFS 2012 and Team Build (please confirm) to build your Visual Studio 2010 project. Though there are soem project types that *must* be upgraded to build in that setup, it seems that yours isn't one of them. But it does look like your Build Agent is missing the components your solution is referencing.  They should either be:

- Referenced as a NuGet Package
- Checked into source control and referenced using relative paths in your project files
- Installed on the build agent